# Integration and step functions, related to Rudin Theorem 6.15

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I'd like any advice I could get about this problem. In general, I feel as though this particular step function has been poorly discussed in class. We are not allowed to assume continuity either, and I'm confused about how to approach this otherwise.

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded, let $a<y<b$ and $\alpha:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\alpha (x)=I(x-y)$.

Prove that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable if and only if $lim_{x\rightarrow y^+}f(x)=f(y)$, and $\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha=f(y)$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of hints that I think show what's going on here pretty well.

$\lim_{x \to y^+} f(x) = f(y)$ will give you right continuity at $y$; notice that you don't need left continuity for the result as the integral has $ \alpha(x) = I(x - y) = 0$ for $y \geq x$.

You partition $[a, b]$ as $a = x_0< x_1 = y < x_2 < x_3 = b$. Then take the limit as $x_2 \to y$ and notice that for any partition an $[x_{n-1}, x_{n}]$ so that $x_{n-1} > y$ we have
$$
M_n \Delta \alpha(x_n) = M_n (I(x_n-y) - I({x_{n-1}-y})) = 0
$$
where $M_n$ is the $\sup$ over the interval $[x_{n-1}, x_n]$; this holds analogously  for the $m_n$, the corresponding $\inf$.

Comment: thanks for this. I am a little confused as to how $U(P,f,\alpha)=M_n(I(x_n-y)-I(x_{n-1}-y))=0$. For instance, wouldn't $M_3(I(x_3-y)-I(x_2-y))$ approach $M_3(1-0)$ as $x^2\rightarrow y$?

Comment: But $M_3$ should be approaching $f(y)$ as $x_2 \to y$ because you are shrinking the interval over which you are considering $\sup f$.